# mysqld got signal 11 server halted

Tags: mysql

Since few days my mysql server halting whole server and I found such information in log

```
150129 21:22:35 [ERROR] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Sort aborted
150306 17:55:55 - mysqld got signal 11 ;
This could be because you hit a bug. It is also possible that this binary
or one of the libraries it was linked against is corrupt, improperly built,
or misconfigured. This error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.
We will try our best to scrape up some info that will hopefully help diagnose
the problem, but since we have already crashed, something is definitely wrong
and this may fail.

key_buffer_size=8384512
read_buffer_size=131072
max_used_connections=101
max_connections=100
threads_connected=29
It is possible that mysqld could use up to
key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_connections = 225787 K
bytes of memory
Hope that's ok; if not, decrease some variables in the equation.

thd=0x2aaab400e500
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
Cannot determine thread, fp=0x47776fa0, backtrace may not be correct.
Stack range sanity check OK, backtrace follows:
(nil)
Stack trace seems successful - bottom reached
Please read http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/using-stack-trace.html and follow instructions on how to resolve the stack trace. Resolved
stack trace is much more helpful in diagnosing the problem, so please do
resolve it
Trying to get some variables.
Some pointers may be invalid and cause the dump to abort...
thd->query at 0x2c22c50 = SELECT id FROM auto_kategorie WHERE lewa_id = 2684
thd->thread_id=8233312
The manual page at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/crashing.html contains
information that should help you find out what is causing the crash.
pure virtual method called

Number of processes running now: 0
150306 17:55:56  mysqld restarted
InnoDB: Log scan progressed past the checkpoint lsn 1 1019637633
150306 17:55:56  InnoDB: Database was not shut down normally!
InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages from the doublewrite
InnoDB: buffer...
InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 1 1019638151
150306 17:55:57  InnoDB: Starting an apply batch of log records to the database...
```

Can you advice what`s the problem here ?

Thanks
Tomek

Comment: Did you check points mentioned here ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5165112/mysql-error-sort-aborted What says `df -h` ?

Comment: Is it always the same?